# Waiting until all AngularJS $resourse paginated requests are finished

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination

I am using AngularJS [`$djResource`](https://github.com/blacklocus/angular-django-rest-resource) for paginated requests to the RESTful Django API. My question is how can I find out when the last paginated request is completed? The problem I am facing is that the promise returned by `$djResource.query()` is marked as resolved as soon as the first page is returned.

My use case: I am loading a paginated list of spots that should be displayed on a map and I have to adjust the map viewport to have all of the spots visible.

Answer (score 1):

Client side is always does not have knowledge about whether current page is last page or not.

Some of the solutions are

Have a `more` property in the response to say whether any more pages

```
{
    ....
    more: false,
    currentPage: 2,
}
```

(or)
Include property `totalPages` in the response

```
{
    ....
    totalPages: 10,
    currentPage: 2,
}
```

(or)
Include property `nextLink` and `previousLink` in the response

```
{
    .... 
    nextLink: /places?page=4,
    previousLink: /places?page=2,
    currentPage: 3,
}
```

Comment: I think it is not 100% correct that the front-end has no knowledge about pagination. I already have total/nextLink/peviousLink attributes in the response and angular-django-rest-resource handles pages on its own (I am using angular-django-rest-resource which is aware of pagination and streams pages into the promise object).

Comment: What you want to achieve?

Comment: As I wrote above, I am loading a paginated list of spots that should be displayed on a map and I have to adjust the map viewport to have all of the spots visible. Obviously, I can do it only after all the spots are loaded. I could, probably, manually iterate through the pages, but I am wondering if there is a nicer way to solve it.

Comment: I guess, you want a tool to fetch all your places automatically. I think, you can have request query option like 'limit=0'. If the limit is zero, then you can sent all the places in a single request instead multiple paginated requests. it save the bandwidth too.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was quite easy: use `success` callback of `$djResource`, which is called after all pages are loaded.